# FtpWebRequest opens random port instead 21

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I want to download files with in my program via FTP. Godaddy servers works only with port 21. However each time I want to connect, connection is rejected because a random port number instead of port 21

The method I use is as below

```
FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + "turcguide.com" + ":21"));
reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypass");
reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
reqFTP.Proxy = null;
reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
WebResponse resp = reqFTP.GetResponse();
```

Using VS 2008 .NET 3.5 on Windows 7 Home Basic OS.

Can some please help what I miss in this method.

The error i get:

> 425 Could not open data connection to port 49756. Connection timeout (port number changes in every run)

Comment: Because it is an FTP client, which is not bound to port 21 (that's the port the server should use). Check GoDaddy documentation to see how you should configure FTP (active or passive and what passive ports should be used).

Comment: @LexLi it works with firefox ftp connection without problem. I checked the info page of godaddy they use port 21 for ftp connections (such as filezilla)
The problem is each time another port is created even I wrote port 21 in my program.

Comment: But I will check if it's active or passive thanks

Comment: Thank you they use reqFTP.UsePassive = true;

Answer (score 1):

You are using an active FTP mode.

In the active mode, a client (`FtpWebRequest` in this case) open a listening port for each transfer, to which a server need to connect to. That port number is random, it cannot be 21. That's a correct behavior. The reason it does not work, is not that the random port is not supported by GoDaddy. The reason is that your Windows firewall prevents GoDaddy from connecting back to that port.

If you do not want the client to open random ports, use a passive mode. In the passive mode, it's the server that opens a port, not the client. In general, you should always use the passive mode, as you want have firewall problems with it. The passive mode is actually the default mode for `FtpWebRequest`. You have explicitly switched to the active mode by this statement:

```
reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
```

Just remove the above line and you'll be good.

For more details, refer to my article on [FTP connection modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).